# Javascript URL redirect if URL starts with a string

Tags: javascript, url, redirect

If someone lands on page with a URL that starts with a string, I'd like to redirect them to another page.

For example, a visitor lands on `website.com/all-books/bookTitle`
I want to redirect them to `website.com/bookTitle`.

But I also have `website.com/all-books/` and I don't want visitors to be redirected if they land there.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
var fromUrl = '/all-books/';
var toUrl = '/';

var fromRegex = "^\\" + fromUrl + "\\/?$";
var match = location.pathname.match(new RegExp(fromRegex, 'i'));
if (match && !window.frameElement) {
  window.location.replace(toUrl);
}
```

This feels like it should be straightforward, but I'm having trouble putting the pieces together. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you share your code please.

Comment: @JorgeMejia Yes, just added it.

Comment: I'm not sure your regex is correct

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could paste the relevant code you have so far.
Something like this may help:

```
var url = window.location.href;
var n = url.lastIndexOf('/');
var uniquekey = url.substring(n + 1);
window.location.replace("website.com/"+uniquekey);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not going about the regex properly.

You have to filter the url properly, and if it matches replace it by removing the directory you want to disable.

Try this:

```
const openedUrl = window.location.href;
let regexPattern = "http.+\/all-books\/.*";
const regexObj = new RegExp(regexPattern);

if(openedUrl.match(regexObj)){
    dirToRemove = "all-books/";
    indexOf = openedUrl.indexOf(dirToRemove);
    const newUrl = openedUrl.slice(0, indexOf) + openedUrl.slice(indexOf+dirToRemove.length);
window.location.replace(newUrl);

};
```

I still think this could be better done using the httpaccess file to make sure a clean redirect occurs. Also, you could use the server scripting if you're using node.js or python etc. to render the website and just return on this address a 302 redirect.

The script above should work though as well, as long as scripting is allowed by client side of course.